# Specific keys swap between working and not working

Tags: keyboard, keys

I've been having a lot of issues on my keyboard as of late, which are getting progressively worse. My **space**, **enter**, **ctrl**,**v**, and **n** keys just simply stop responding!

But here's the kick - they sometimes work, and they sometimes don't! About every minute or so, all 5 of those keys stop working at all. Then about a minute later they come back and work just fine. This process repeats and it is quite annoying - especially as a grad student who spends 99% of my time at my laptop! :)

Anyway, I'm running Ubuntu 18.04 LTS on an Asus Q555LF, and this problem has been occurring for a few months, but the intervals have been getting smaller. Restarting my laptop does nothing to help, and even once I wiped the hardrive and reinstalled Ubuntu to no avail.

Does anyone know anything about this? Is there any way I can test my keys independent from Ubuntu, without having to install Windows?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Cleaned the keyboard? Try a USB keyboard that's known good? If the USB keyboard has the same problem at the same time, that's definitely a software issue, otherwise hardware

Comment: To test keyboard independent from Ubuntu, download a live CD of another distribution and start a live session.